# User Registration Alphanumeric issue

Tags: php, database, user-registration

I'm having some issues with my user registration system--namely the CheckUsername function inside of it.

This code:

```
    function checkUsername($username) {
        if ( preg_match('/\s/',$username)) {
            return false;
        }
        if(!preg_match('/^[\w\-]+$/', $username)) {
            return false;
        }
        if(strlen($username) == 0) {
            return false;   
        }
        else {
            $sql = "SELECT count(username) FROM users WHERE username = :username LIMIT 1";
            $que = $this->db->prepare($sql);
            $que->bindParam('username', $username);
            try {
                $que->execute();
                while($row = $que->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)) {

                    if($row[0] > 0) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    else {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(PDOException $e) {}
        }
    }
```

Isn't working as designed. Users are able to register with names like `<script>`, which I clearly do not want.

```
        function registerUser($password, $username)
    {
        if(!$this->checkUsername($username))
        {
            header('location:index.php');
        }
        else
        {
        $password = $this->passwordEncryption($password);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users(username, password) VALUES (:username, :password);";
        $sql .= "INSERT INTO bank_accounts(balance, fuel_cell, energy_cell) VALUES (100,100, 100);";
        $que = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $que->bindParam('username', $username);
        $que->bindParam('password', $password);
        try{
             $que->execute(); 
             $que->nextRowset();
             $this->login($username, $password);
             }

             catch(PDOException $e){}
        }
    }
```

Comment: could you show how you use this function ?

Comment: @Ziollek, i've added the actual user registration function to the original post as well.

Answer (score 1):

This states **if there is not a word character or -** so any string that contains a word character or - and anything else is OK:

```
if(!preg_match('/^[\w\-]+$/', $username)) {
    return false;
}
```

You probably want **if there is any character that is not a word character or -**

```
if(preg_match('/[^\w\-]+$/', $username)) {
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following :)

```
function checkUsername($username) {
    $username = trim("$username");

    if ( empty($username) || !preg_match("/^a-z0-9\-]+$/i", $username)) {
        return false;
    }

    $sql = "SELECT count(1) FROM users WHERE username = :username LIMIT 1";
    $que = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $que->bindParam('username', $username);
    try{ 
        $que->execute(); 
        while($row = $que->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)) { 
            if($row[0] > 0) {
                return false;
            } else {
            return true;
            }
        }  
    } catch(PDOException $e){}
}
```